# Debian 9.2: Setting Up SFTP Service with Public Key Autentication and PGP

Tags: debian, sftp, gpg, pgp

My final goal is to create a SFTP server coupled with a PGP authentication as described here: [SFTP+PGP](https://xcesstek.wordpress.com/2012/10/21/setting-up-sftp-service-with-public-key-autentication-and-pgp-support/).

Actually I succeeded to create a `sftp_user` user who can connect to his own  directory on my server via SFTP with his username and password.
(I followed this great procedure [Setting up SFTP](https://memo-linux.com/mettre-en-place-un-serveur-sftp-sous-debian-8/)).

Now, I want to allow him to connect with a key file generated by PGP without using a password.

I've already generated a PGP key but i can't assign it to my user **sftp_user**.

So what is the procedure for achieve this?

I can only connect in SSH for setting up the environment.